# Entity Framework 5 Advice - Summary View

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a View I am using to sum the number of times a tag has been used to describe a project in our application. There is an array of Tags attached to each Project, and when displaying the Tags I want to show how many other times is was used (and link through to the other projects). The Tag Object looks like

```
public class Tag {
    public int TagID { get; set; }
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public string TagValue { get; set; }

    //public int TagCount { get {LINQ Query returning count from View}; }
}
```

The view is simply the TagValue and a count of occurrences. My questions are:

1. Should I be using Views with EF like this?
2. What is the most elegant way to Query a view like this?
3. Where and how to I make EF aware of this view so I can use LINQ to query it like I would any other Entity?

Comment: Faster than _what_? Did you have it different, changed it, then retested the performance and found that it's faster now?

Comment: I was experiencing some slowness when trying to load Tags which matched a TagValue. I am unsure if other stuff was happening in the backend though (i.e. if the Project / other Entities were loading to slow this down). Using a view with an index to set an additional property on the Tag class seemed more elegant (but perhaps is the wrong direction?)

Comment: Don't make guesses - find out what's wrong instead. Use a profiler to see where your application is spending its time.

Comment: To ask differently, I feel this is a better and more readable / maintainable approach to collecting this information. Especially if expanded to create a list of Projects with each tag. Am I off base there as well? I spent little time working on the performance as I felt it was a bad solution in the first place, and perhaps should have left that out of my question altogether?

Comment: You can map to a view just as you can map to a table. Maybe you have to add a key manually in the EF model.

Comment: I would not put a linq query inside an entity class though.

Comment: So, is there a recommended way to accomplish a somewhat processing intensive derived property or field like this?

Comment: If it is too slow, I would like to have a count column in each tag to keep the current count. It will hard to maintain though ..

Comment: Agreed - I feel this should be easily accomplished in Code - I just don't know how to best approach it, and where best to store the result to return to the View.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-asked the core of what I was attempting to ask above here, with answer:
[Entity Framework with Calculated Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13882899/entity-framework-with-calculated-property)

Thank you everyone who commented!