# How to make a smart select based on Tags, Time and votes (Reddit)?

Tags: .net, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Say that we got the following tables :

**Posts**

- Votes(up/down)
- Tags
- CreatedDate

**Users**

- Tags

Now we need to generate a special list that sorts like this :

- Up/Down votes
- CreatedDate
- Tags(that the current user listen on)

This list should be based on the main flow of posts but then with a mix of post where tags that I listen on is a bit higher rated then others.

You could say that I need to create something like reddit.com got on there first page.

How should I do this?

Comment: Im on the planning stage but my thoughts have been a couple of diffrent approaches where the best is to add a column to the Post that have a calculated score(done every 12 hours) based on votes and time and then when a specific user asks for a list all posts that correspond to the users taggs will get modifier in some way to make the post to get higher score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out my asked question here, I think it roughly addresses your same problem of how to load calculated values (in my case by using a ViewModel and query to the repository - a MVC app using the repository pattern). In your case, perhaps you maintain a view in the DB with your aggregated data so you are doing some of intensive calculation on an insert rather than on a read?

[Entity Framework with Calculated Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13882899/entity-framework-with-calculated-property)